# How to properly fill an NxN matrix

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, linear-algebra

I have been trying to create an NxN square matrix (the size of the square matrix is determined by the user) but seem to have run into an issue. The displayed matrix is actually a symmetric matrix which is not what I am trying to as I want to be able to have each value hold a unique integer. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int size = 1;
    int array [size][size];
    
    printf ("Enter the size you would like for the nxn matrix: ");
    scanf ("%d", &size);
    
    printf ("Now enter elements into the matrix. \n");
    
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
       for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
       {
          printf ("[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
          scanf ("%d", &array [i][j]);
       }
    }
    printf ("------------------------\n\n");
    
    printf ("the matrix is: \n\n");
    
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
       for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
       {
          printf ("  %d  ", array [i][j]);
       }
       printf ("\n");
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `int array [size][size];` that is a fixed size array. It does not change size just because you later change the value of the `size` variable. Either move that line to be after the `scanf` or better still use dynamic allocation.

Comment: You cannot just use array[i][j] syntax for the printf and scanf because the compiler has no idea where the next row starts

Comment: @Edmund: if you use a compiler that supports C99, C11, or C18 (and you should be using such a compiler — there aren't many good reasons to use something that only supports C90, which is 30 years old as a standard!), and if the code is fixed to define `array` after `size` is scanned and validated, then you can use the `array[i][j]` notation perfectly well.  If you want to use `malloc()` to avoid stack overflow, you can write `int (*array)[size] = malloc(size * size * sizeof(array[0][0]));` (and check that it was successful) and still use `array[i][j]` notation.  That's a pointer to a VLA.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    // Create variables
    int i, j, size;
    
    // Create 2D array
    printf ("Enter the size you would like for the nxn matrix: ");
    scanf ("%d", &size);
    int *array = (int *)malloc(size * size * sizeof(int)); 
    
    // Fill 2D array with values
    printf ("Now enter elements into the matrix. \n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
       for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
       {
          printf ("[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
          scanf ("%d", &array[i * size + j]);
       }
    }
    printf ("------------------------\n\n");
    
    // Display values of 2D array
    printf ("the matrix is: \n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
       for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
       {
          printf ("%d", array[i * size + j]);
       }
       printf ("\n");
    }
    
    free(array);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You should explain what you changed.  You should check that the `scanf()` on size worked, and that the number given by the user is plausible (strictly positive, and not too big — maybe up to 1024).  Since you use `malloc()`, you don't have to worry about stack overflow whereas with a VLA, you do have to worry about that.  You should check that the `scanf()` operations in the loop work correctly; you don't have to validate the numbers.  You need to put some space between numbers on each line when printing the matrix.  (My personal bête noire: you don't need a space before the printed newlines.)

Comment: You should think about using `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)` for your loop controls.  Then you don't need to declare `i` (or `j`) at the top of the function.